# annotation Transformer Invocation

Tags: java, testng

I would like to use annotation transformer in my code, after reading the reference. I am still not fully understand how to invoke annotation transformer to my orignal code programmatically(I read it before http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). Suppose I have the following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class TestNGTest {

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testCase2" })
   public void testCase1() {
      System.out.println("in test case 1");
   }

   @Test
   public void testCase2() {
      System.out.println("in test case 2");
   }



   public static class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transform(final ITestAnnotation annotation, final Class testClass,
                final Constructor testConstructor, final Method testMethod) {
           //some transformations of my annotation
        }


   }
}
```

How can I invoke "transform" programmatically?
Thank you very much for you help in advance
Would you mind provide me some simple sample code?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for those who read this post. 
Finally, I understand what is the problem, the answer is very simple:

```
@Test
public void verifyAnnotationWithTransformer() {
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    MyTransformer myTransformer = new MyTransformer();
    tng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {TestNGTest.class});
    tng.setAnnotationTransformer(myTransformer);
    tng.run();
}
```

The point is second last line that one put the whole object of the annoation transformer in the function setAnnotationTransformer. I do not notice there is such a function before. I am stupid. =_="
Once again thank you for those who may try to help.